# Spark SQL Calculating wrong dense rank on large data sets

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dense-rank

I am calculating dense rank over a table of around 1M rows. The problem is that the resultant data set doesn't have correct calculating of ranks.

Why is it so?

The maximum element in dataset is not assigned 100 percentile or highest rank.
As we know spark sql works on data chunks/partitions of data to speed up processing
do you think this might be the issue?

Rank : dense_rank

| Column A | Expected Rank A | Wrong Rank A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 6 | 2 |
| 44 | 5 | 1 |
| 31 | 4 | 5 |
| 25 | 3 | 4 |
| 21 | 2 | 3 |
| 21 | 2 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 | 1 |

```
select named_struct('JobName','Traffic') AS headers,
       named_struct('data',named_struct('companyId',CompanyId,'trafficPercentile',percentile,'pageViewsCount',pageViewsCount,'category','Traffic')) as payload
from (
    select *,(dense_rank/dist_cnt) * 100 as percentile
    from(
        select CompanyId,pageViewsCount,(dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY pageViewsCount)) as dense_rank,TotalEmployees,(select count(distinct(pageViewsCount)) from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 1 and TotalEmployees <= 10) as dist_cnt
        from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 1 and TotalEmployees <= 10
    )
    union
    select *,(dense_rank/dist_cnt) * 100 as percentile
    from(
        select CompanyId,pageViewsCount,(dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY pageViewsCount)) as dense_rank,TotalEmployees,(select count(distinct(pageViewsCount)) from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 11 and TotalEmployees <= 50) as dist_cnt
        from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 11 and TotalEmployees <= 50
    ) 
    union
    select *,(dense_rank/dist_cnt) * 100 as percentile
    from(
        select CompanyId,pageViewsCount,(dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY pageViewsCount)) as dense_rank,TotalEmployees,(select count(distinct(pageViewsCount)) from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 51 and TotalEmployees <= 200) as dist_cnt
        from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 51 and TotalEmployees <= 200
    )
    union
    select *,(dense_rank/dist_cnt) * 100 as percentile
    from(
        select CompanyId,pageViewsCount,(dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY pageViewsCount)) as dense_rank,TotalEmployees,(select count(distinct(pageViewsCount)) from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 201 and TotalEmployees <= 500) as dist_cnt
        from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 201 and TotalEmployees <= 500
    )
    union
    select *,(dense_rank/dist_cnt) * 100 as percentile
    from(
        select CompanyId,pageViewsCount,(dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY pageViewsCount)) as dense_rank,TotalEmployees,(select count(distinct(pageViewsCount)) from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 501 and TotalEmployees <= 1000) as dist_cnt
        from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 501 and TotalEmployees <= 1000
    )
    union
    select *,(dense_rank/dist_cnt) * 100 as percentile
    from(
        select CompanyId,pageViewsCount,(dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY pageViewsCount)) as dense_rank,TotalEmployees,(select count(distinct(pageViewsCount)) from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 1001 and TotalEmployees <= 5000) as dist_cnt
        from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 1001 and TotalEmployees <= 5000
    )
    union
    select *,(dense_rank/dist_cnt) * 100 as percentile
    from(
        select CompanyId,pageViewsCount,(dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY pageViewsCount)) as dense_rank,TotalEmployees,(select count(distinct(pageViewsCount)) from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 5001 and TotalEmployees <= 10000) as dist_cnt
        from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 5001 and TotalEmployees <= 10000
    )
    union
    select *,(dense_rank/dist_cnt) * 100 as percentile
    from(
        select CompanyId,pageViewsCount,(dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY pageViewsCount)) as dense_rank,TotalEmployees,(select count(distinct(pageViewsCount)) from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 10001 and TotalEmployees <= 50000) as dist_cnt
        from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 10001 and TotalEmployees <= 50000
    )
    union
    select *,(dense_rank/dist_cnt) * 100 as percentile
    from(
        select CompanyId,pageViewsCount,(dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY pageViewsCount)) as dense_rank,TotalEmployees,(select count(distinct(pageViewsCount)) from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 50001 and TotalEmployees <= 100000) as dist_cnt
        from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 50001 and TotalEmployees <= 100000
    )
    union
    select *,(dense_rank/dist_cnt) * 100 as percentile
    from(
        select CompanyId,pageViewsCount,(dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY pageViewsCount)) as dense_rank,TotalEmployees,(select count(distinct(pageViewsCount)) from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 100001) as dist_cnt
        from pv
        where TotalEmployees >= 100001
    ) order by TotalEmployees

)
```

In this query I need to calculate percentile on blocks of data governed by totalEmployees individually.

Output count : 1M

Comment: Can you share sample code and input dataset? Ranks are not global but calculated within partition so most probably you need to take a look at your window definition

Comment: Hi @M_S have added the sample query

Comment: It's very hard to see what's happening here without seeing the input data. You have a lot of union operations and I'd expect there to be multiple rank 1, 2, 3,... for each `select` in the union. Is it possible to construct a minimal example that's reproducing the issue?

Side note: `(dense_rank/dist_cnt) * 100 as percentile` is probably incorrect since `dense_rank` doesn't produce gaps. You have to use `rank` in the same way or simply `percent_rank` without the normalization.